# Menu doesn't appear

Tags: android

Hy!

I want to make my first Menue

I just createt the folder /res/menu and the file menu.xml

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/quit"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:title="Quit" />
</menu>
```

In my code i add:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  Main.this.finish();
  return true;
}
```

If i start my app and press the menu button nothing appear.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Instead of your second group of code, try using this instead: this will fix your problem because you need to use onCreateOptionsMenu instead of onCreateContextMenu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.quit: 
           finish();
           return true;
         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
}
```

Comment: no problem, click the little check mark below the 1 to select this as your selected answer!

Comment: on question: i have a thread which download every 3 seconds data from the inet but when i press close i think the thread is still alive? any solution?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680180/where-to-stop-destroy-threads-in-android-service-class

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things in `onCreateContextMenu`. This is the menu that comes up when you long press  To add things to the menu you get hitting the menu button, you want to do them in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` insteald of `onCreateContextMenu()` and secondly, in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` you should do the following:

```
@Overrid
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.[your desired item id here]:
            //do what you want to do for this item!
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope that helps!