# Android service continues to run after force stop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I have a `Service` that spawns a `Thread` to connect to a third-party and it runs fine.  However, if I go to settings and stop the service, it continues to run.  It disappears from the Running Services in settings and the `onDestroy` method is called, but I still see each method in the `Service` being called.  I'm assuming that I'm not using the `Thread` correctly, but I don't see why the service would continue running... unless it keeps running until all of the threads are done.

```
public class DataProcessorService extends Service {

    private ServiceState _state;
    private ConnectThread _connectThread;

    private Handler _handler = new Handler() {
        public synchronized void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            stopConnectThread();
            onNextState();  // Goes to state after Connecting
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        logger.debug("onCreate called");

        _state = ServiceState.readState(this);

        switch (_state) {
        ...
        case CONNECTING:
            onConnecting();
            break;
        ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        logger.debug("onDestroy called");
        stopConnectThread();
        ServiceState.saveState(this, _state);
    }

    private void onConnecting() {
        _state = ServiceState.CONNECTING;
        logger.debug("onConnecting called");

        _connectThread = new ConnectThread(this, _handler);
        _connectThread.setDaemon(true);
        _connectThread.start();
    }

    private void stopConnectThread() {
        if (_connectThread != null) {
            _connectThread.interrupt();
            _connectThread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my `ConnectThread` class (I also tried doing what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680180/where-to-stop-destroy-threads-in-android-service-class/686570#686570) which is the commented sections):

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final Context _context;
    private final Handler _handler;

//    private volatile Thread runner;

    public ConnectThread(Context context, Handler handler) {
        super("ConnectThread");
        this._context = context;
        this._handler = handler;
    }

//    public synchronized void startThread() {
//        if (runner == null) {
//            runner = new Thread(this);
//            runner.start();
//        }
//    }
//
//    public synchronized void stopThread() {
//        if (runner != null) {
//            Thread moribund = runner;
//            runner = null;
//            moribund.interrupt();
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
//        if (Thread.currentThread() == runner) {
            logger.debug("Service started");

            Thread.sleep(5000); //inside try-catch
//        }
        Looper.loop();
    }

}
```

When I look in DDMS, it shows multiple `ConnectThread`s and they're each in the `wait` status, so I'm assuming they're finishing and not being killed and that may be preventing my Service from stopping.  Does anyone see why the issue is happening, or know how to fix it?

**EDIT:** I'm now starting to think it may be because I need a `Looper.quit()` call somewhere.  I'll need to read up on `Looper` and `Handler` more.  I started to look at `HandlerThread` but I'm not real clear on what Loopers are for, yet.  Is passing a `Handler` to my `ConnectThread` a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the Looper from looping in stopConnectThread(). Just interrupting the Thread doesn't won't stop the Looper. Try this:

in ConnectThread class add:

```
private Looper myLooper; // A reference to the Looper for this Thread
public void stopLooper() {
    // Tell Looper to stop looping
    myLooper.quit();
}
```

in ConnectThread.run() method, after `Looper.prepare()` add:

```
myLooper = Looper.myLooper(); // Get the Looper associated with this Thread
```

in stopConnectThread(), instead of `_connectThread.interrupt();` do this:

```
_connectThread.stopLooper();
```