# Stop running execution of JNI method

Tags: android, multithreading, java-native-interface, thread-safety, android-handler

I have executing method (for example **JNI.calculate(listener)**)of JNI library. It should takes for example 30 seconds. I wanted but executing this method **calculate(listener)** again but first I need to stop last executing. This method has one parameter - listener, that has two methods:

```
public void canContinue(){
      return canContinue;
}

public void result(int number){
      //some code
}
```

The method *canContinue* calls asynchronous, **for example** every 3 seconds. I just dont want to wait, until next *canContinue* will be called. I wanted to immediatelly execute next execution of this method **calculate(listener)**.

Do you have any recommendations? Probably I should use *Handler, HandlerThread, Thread, AsyncTask* or som sort of this classes, but how to figure it out?

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm trying to stop FFmpeg's execution (after calling it's main C function using Java native method) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664689/stop-cancel-execution-of-ffmpeg-command

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand the question correctly but i think keeping a delay will do the trick, to keep delay write this

```
try {       
      Thread.sleep(1000); // time in milliseconds
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: That is bad way how to do that. I could blocked the UI and the separating Thread. There must be a better way, I think. @Redman

Answer (score 0):

What if you call your function ***JNI.calculate(listener)*** from a **Thread** ? You can ***start*** that Thread which calls this function, and when you want an other and immediate execution, ***interrupt*** the Thread and ***start*** another (never restart a terminated thread!). Be careful with manipulated data: you should use a **mutex** to prevent it.

See that too (it's about thread interruption and gives some precisions):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378525/6523232

Comment: The method JNI.calculate(listener) is running on separate Thread, that is out of logic of the Android app. @N0un

Comment: I understand. I found that too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14814420/6523232 @user997777