# Is this a prefect way to stop handlerthread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I always create two handler: one is wraping on main thread, another is wraping on a single thread.

Is this a best method to start and stop these in an Activity lifecycle?

```
HandlerThread safeThread = null;
Handler safeHandler = null;
Handler handler = null;


@Override
    public void onStart() {

if (safeThread == null) {
            safeThread = new HandlerThread("safeThread");
            safeThread.start();
            safeHandler = new Handler(safeThread.getLooper());
        } else if (safeThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
            safeThread.start();
            safeHandler = new Handler(safeThread.getLooper());
        } else if (safeThread.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING) {
            safeHandler = new Handler(safeThread.getLooper());
        } else if (safeThread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
            safeThread = null;
            safeThread = new HandlerThread("safeThread");
            safeThread.start();
            safeHandler = new Handler(safeThread.getLooper());
        }
}




protected void onStop() {
        Log.d("x", "onStop is executed");
        safeHandler = null;
        safeThread.quit();
        safeThread.interrupt();
        safeThread = null;
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Comment: safeThread.interrupt(); is best way to stop thread

Comment: yes , i know but i thinking about is this safe when i after interrupt and null this.

Comment: i have given answer..one thing i would suggest you as you are new on stackoverflow.IF you want to appreciate someone help then give him a vote and if you think answer is best then mark it as answer..:) welcome and cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a safe way to stop threads:

```
 if (safeThread!= null) {
     safeThread.quit();
     safeThread = null; // Object is no more required.
 }
```

You can use `safeThread.quitsafely` as well.

Comment: For more details see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680180/where-to-stop-destroy-threads-in-android-service-class

Comment: can you explain more details ?? what the reason ??

Comment: For Reason see question in my above comment

Comment: The question was about `HandlerThread`. This response is about `Thread`. If the `Handler` part isn't important, this answer needs to note that, and explain why.

Answer (score 25):

I know it's a somewhat old question, but I stumble across it looking for the same answer and further researching I don't believe the current answer applies very well to HandlerThread (although absolutely correct for normal threads)

HandlerThread have a builtin `quit()` and `quitSafely`(API18) methods to stop the thread.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html#quit()

the difference between the two is only if the messages in queue will be processed before it stops or not.

so to answer, it's as simple as:

```
safeThread.quit();
```

Comment: To add clarity: quit() is available in API 5

Comment: What to do before api 18?

Comment: Does quit() or quitSafely() stops Thread or only the Looper that thread has to handle messages? It does not explain if it ends thread or not [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html#quit()).

Comment: @Thracian the looper is a for-loop cycle that runs in `HandlerThread#run()` method forever. This prevents the `run()` method from reaching the end, thus keeping the `Thread` alive. The `Thread` is terminated right after the looper is quit.

Answer (score 17):

If you start the thread like this:

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
thread.start();
```

The safest way to stop it would be:

```
thread.quitSafely();
```

**quitSafely** ensures that all pending messages are processed before the thread stops.

Note: My original answer included an additional call to **thread.join**, but I found the **join** call does not release reliably when used after **quitSafely**.

Comment: I'm also wondering whether I need to join after quitSafely. Can you clarify "does not release reliably"? Thanks!

Comment: @Kaifei I recall I was observing that the join call just blocks the thread. That was back in August, so not 100% sure.

Comment: quitSafely was key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been following this :

```
if (safeHandler!= null) {
     final Looper looper = safeHandler.getLooper();
     looper.quitSafely();
     safeHandler = null;
 }
```