# android - How to stop the running thread safely

Tags: java, android

My application has two activities. 
Activity one(A1) starts the thread.
Let's suppose this activity(A1) goes to pause-state.
I want to stop the running thread safely; how to do this?

thanks

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680180/where-to-stop-destroy-threads-in-android-service-class) previously answered question, or you could paste some of your relevant code .

Comment: A really good link!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use **return** statement in your Threads run method like this ...

```
public void run(){

    if(isDone)
    {     
      return;
    }

}
```

or you can use this ...

```
if(thread != null)
{
    Thread t1 = thread;
    thread = null;
    t1.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you having a look at the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

Answer (score 0):

//use boolean flag in side run method of `Thread` as following

```
boolean isActivityPaused = false;

       public void run(){

    // use isActivityPaused boolean flag here to stop your Thread

        while(!isActivityPaused){ 



        }

        }
```

now this is `onPause()` methed of your `Activity`

```
public void onPause(){

isActivityPaused = true; // set isActivityPaused= true to stop your `Thread`

}
```